# How to change Layer

Tags: java, android, google-maps, tile

I've asked below question on Japanese service of like stacoverflow but anyone didn't answered.
So, let me ask here. Please excuse my bad English.

I'm using Tile Overlay of Google Maps API for Android ver and 2 layers.
Then I want to change the Layer.
To explain it is too hard for me in English... So please read code of what I wrote.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mTileOverlay != null && seekBar.getProgress() > 50) {

                    mTileOverlay.remove();      
                    setupOverlayLayersA(_mMap); //set Layer A
                    mTileOverlay.setTransparency(1.0f - ((float) progress - 50f) / 50f);


                }else if (seekBar.getProgress() == 50) {

                    mTileOverlay.setTransparency(1.0f); 

                }else if(seekBar.getProgress() < 50){

                    mTileOverlay.remove();      
                    setupOverlayLayersB(_mMap); //set Layer B
                    mTileOverlay.setTransparency((float) progress / (float) 50);

                }
            }
```

This Problem is to repeat "remove" and "setup layer" when seek progress is changed. What I want to do is to change layer just one time when seek progress is over 50 or less than 50 and to enable transparency
How should I fix the code?

*What I want to do is like this...

SeekBar

B--------------50--------------A
|----------------------------------|

Transparency

B--------------50--------------A
0.0f----------1.0f------------0.0f

Comment: And what problem is actually happening?  Also in you code, consider what will happen if `mTileOverlay == null && seekBar.getProgress() == 50` - NPE でしょう。

Comment: The problem is to be repeated to remove layer and set new layer whenever progress is changed even same layer is used. It means when progress is 51, current layer ( in this case is A) is removed and set new layer A and changed 52, current layer A is removed and new layer A is set.

Comment: and what is not working? Have you put in debug statements to check that it is being called?

Comment: No, It is actually working but this is bad because of repeating "remove" and "setup" whenever progress is changed. I want to set a layer one time when a seekbar is on 51 or 49. 51 is Layer A and 49 is Layer B.

Comment: So you want to remove only once when it passes a certain threshold?  Maybe introduce a `boolean` variable indicating that it has already been removed.

Comment: I'm sorry that my description is too bad to explain.

Comment: Please provide the link to the Japanese StackOverflow

Comment: You mean boolean variable is "fromUser" ?? I have to do re-reading onProgressChanged() method.

Comment: I am not quite sure I am understanding your requirements, but why can you not change your code so that `if (seekBar.getProgress() == 51) addLayerA`  `if (seekBar.getProgress() == 49) addLayerB` ?

Comment: I've just resolved this problem!!! thanks to you!!!  I had tried like your code before but I could not. a while ago, I changed below Answer. I was totally complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(mTileOverlay != null && seekBar.getProgress() > 50) {           

               if(seekBar.getProgress() == 51){
                mTileOverlay.remove();      
                setupOverlayLayersA(_mMap); //set Layer A
               }

                mTileOverlay.setTransparency(1.0f - ((float) progress - 50f) / 50f);


            }else if (seekBar.getProgress() == 50) {

                mTileOverlay.setTransparency(1.0f); 

            }else if(seekBar.getProgress() < 50){

               if(seekBar.getProgress() == 49){
                mTileOverlay.remove();      
                setupOverlayLayersB(_mMap); //set Layer B
               }

                mTileOverlay.setTransparency((float) progress / (float) 50);

            }
        }
```